# Python error: “IndexError: string index out of range”

Tags: python, udp

**I am new in python, how to fix this?**

```
if data[0] != chr(0):
    if data[12:16] in self.clients:
        os.write(self.tfd, data)
        self.clients[data[12:16]]["aliveTime"] = time.time()
        self.clients[data[12:16]]["localIPn"] = src
    else:
```

> File "/etc/proxy/proxy.py", line 82, in run
>       if data[0] != chr(0): IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: Posting it twice doesn't make it a better question, and it doesn't make it more likely to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Data [0] Means nothing for compare !